# Is there a way to execute python code from an HTML button without changing the url?

Tags: python, flask

I am currently using a form submit button:

```
<form action="/submit" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Generate Word" >
</form>
```

The python script is executed with:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods = ['POST'])
def sumbit():
```

Is there another way to exectute the code without making the url have "/submit" at the end?

Comment: Should be able to change the methods of the page the form is on to `methods=['GET', 'POST']`, and then use `<form action="submit()" method="post">`

Comment: Maybe you need ajax.

Comment: Do you know what the ajax code would be?

Answer (score 1):

You can name submit anything you like, as long as the action in the form matches the route url in the flask app.

js:

```
<form action="/magic" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Generate Word" >
</form>
```

python:

```
@app.route('/magic', methods = ['POST'])
def magic():
```

EDIT:

if you don't want to use ajax, you could also send the form to `/magic`, and then redirect back to the index again.

```
@app.route('/magic', methods = ['POST'])
def magic():
    do_something(request.form)
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: I didn't mean changing he URL specifically to "/submit", I mean avoid changing the URL completely. Your example would just change the URL to "/magic"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I got to work:

Python:

```
@app.route('/submit/', methods = ['POST'])
def sumbit():
```

JS:

```
  $('.btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/submit/",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                $('#results').html(resp.data);
            }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the HTML code to:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Generate Word" >
</form>
```

And change the python code to:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def submit():
```

This should avoid your page from going to "/submit"